# ERROR TypeError: changes.forEach is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, foreach, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error when trying to fetch data from firestore (angular/ionic)

**PizzaProvider.ts**

```
getAllPizzas() {
    return this._afs.collection<Pizzas>('pizzas', ref => ref);
}
```

**pizzas-list.ts**

```
pizzas: Observable<any[]>;
// Function
this.pizzas = this._pizzaProvider.getAllPizzas().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(arr => arr.map(doc => {
        return { id: doc.payload.doc.id, ...doc.payload.doc.data() }
     }))
 );
```

and i got the error :

```
ERROR TypeError: changes.forEach is not a function
 at combineChanges (changes.js:19)
    at ScanSubscriber.accumulator (changes.js:15)
    at ScanSubscriber._tryNext (scan.js:111)
    at ScanSubscriber._next (scan.js:104)
    at ScanSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
```

What i'm doing wrong pls ?

Comment: Probably you are not getting an array back from this method `return this._afs.collection<Pizzas>('pizzas', ref => ref);`

Comment: i'm getting this with console log :

`AngularFirestoreCollection {ref: CollectionReference, query: CollectionReference}
query
:
CollectionReference
firestore
:
Firestore {_queue: AsyncQueue, INTERNAL: {…}, _config: FirestoreConfig, _databaseId: DatabaseId, _dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
id
:
(...)
parent
:
(...)
path
:
(...)
_query
:
Query
endAt
:
null
explicitOrderBy
:
[]
filters
:
[]
limit
:
null
memoizedCanonicalId
:
null
memoizedOrderBy`

Comment: why are you passing `ref => ref` in the collection? console.log the response from `this._pizzaProvider.getAllPizzas().snapshotChanges()` by `subscribe` on it.

Comment: did you try removing  `ref => ref` from the collection?

Comment: i got this : `Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}`

Comment: yes i removed it

Comment: Check the value of `_subscriptions: ` the array.

Comment: like this link https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges

Comment: _subscriptions:  says null

Comment: Are you missing a `return` at map(arr => return arr.map(doc => {`

Comment: I did like the same code in the previous link, i get this when I log it : `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution !**

I had to downgrade firebase to 4.13.1 from 5.0.2

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1611